# Location tracking in Flutter for Android & iOS devices

Tags: geolocation, location, background-process, tracking

Need help to figure out a possible solution for both iOS & Android. I'm building a Flutter app that is in constant communication with the backend Laravel application that manages the database.

How to run this particular app in the background to track the location and communicate back to its Laravel backend application with an API in an interval of 15 seconds, even if the phone is idle / screen is off??

Currently, when the app is active in the foreground, it fetches the location and does the API communication to store the location data.